# What motivated Laird to retcon Venus in Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles?

Tags: teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Teenage_Mutant_Ninja_Turtles_characters#Venus_de_Milo) explains this character best

> Venus de Milo was a female Ninja turtle who appeared in Ninja Turtles: The Next Mutation. In a 2007 interview director Kevin Munroe elaborated on the instructions Peter Laird gave to him for TMNT. Munroe admitted that among those rules was, "**There’s absolutely no mention of Venus de Milo, the female Turtle. You can’t even joke about that with Peter. It’s just one of those things that he hates with a passion.**"

Is there any indication of why she was retconned out? He was a writer on the show, so was this something he'd always been against or did he change his mind?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't the only time a writer was told similar instructions. Image Comics' was told the "no girl turtles".

Part of it has to deal with the association with the fail live action, part of it is Laird's hatred for the character. ([wikia page](http://tmnt.wikia.com/wiki/Venus_de_Milo#Reception)))

In a recent [blog post](http://peterlairdstmntblog.blogspot.com/2012/03/few-musings-on-turtles-as-aliens.html) about the Micheal Bay movie he wrote this:

> Over the years, I have made no secret of my distaste for what I consider to be the weak, facile, creatively bankrupt idea which can be summed up like this:
>
> > "If FOUR Ninja Turtles are good, then FIVE (or more) Ninja Turtles MUST be better!"
>
> It was in large part this brain-dead notion that led to the creation of the execrable "Venus de Milo" character in the blessedly short-lived live action TV series  "Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles: The Next Mutation".

This may also reflect why Venus is viewed by some as a "The Scrappy Do" character on TvTropes.

Comment: It also, of course, messes with the "boys club" aspect of TMNT if they start letting girls in.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots next thing you know, they will start having boy *My Little Ponies*. Oh wait, they already did.

Comment: @Robert Columbia Except that boy *My Little Ponies* weren't written exclusively for the purpose of being with the female ponies. Venus de Milo was introduced to the show so that one of the brothers would have a love interest. Also, they decided that she would be practicing a form of Chinese magic called shinobi (never mind that the word "shinobi" is not only Japanese, but has nothing to do with magic whatsoever, as it simply means "ninja").