# Does Venus De Milo appear again?

Tags: comics, teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles

Venus was a female Ninja turtle who appeared in Ninja Turtles: The Next Mutation. I know that she is [now banned from ever appearing again](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/13550/3804). Has this ban held? Or did she ever appear in the Comics or subsequent TV series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other then the crossover between Power Rangers and the tv show merchandise, she makes no other appearances. There is a gag that mention a female turtle in a comic but never mentioned again in any canon media.

[Other Appearances of Venus](http://tmnt.wikia.com/wiki/Venus_de_Milo#Other_Appearances)